# How to obtain the caller's IP address in Flask/Connexion?

Tags: python, flask, http-headers, swagger, connexion

I'm using an OpenAPI 3.0 specification (swagger.yml) and use Swagger Codegen to create the corresponding Python Flask application stubs. This is how I run the application to expose my Swagger API:

```
app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./swagger/')
app.app.json_encoder = encoder.JSONEncoder
app.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': 'My Test API'})
# add CORS support to send Access-Control-Allow-Origin header
CORS(app.app)
```

So far so good. The application logic is handled within the generated Python stubs which are linked by the `x-openapi-router-controller: swagger_server.controllers.user_controller`.

I now however need to access **HTTP Request specific information within the application** itself to for example react differently based on the **HTTP_CLIENT_IP address**

How can I obtain that information within my controller endpoint?

Comment: so far I only have found something that seems to be a work around this issue: https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/issues/491

Answer (score 0):

Use Flask's `request` context.

For example, to get the HTTP_CLIENT_IP, use:

```
from flask import request

http_client_ip = request.remote_addr
```

You can read more about `request` [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/).

Answer (score 0):

Attached two related links addressing the same issue on [request header parameters](https://github.com/zalando/connexion/issues/850) and how [connexion does not forward them](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request.html#header-parameters) to custom controllers. I ended up manually accessing them via

```
access_token = connexion.request.headers['access_token']
```